# ASP.NET MVC inserts string inside new object parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have tried to insert a string variable inside a `textboxfor` to complete his parameters, but the result is something as `variablename=.....`

For example, if I want disable the `textbox` depending on `boolean` in the `modelview` :

```
@string isDisabled = (Model.kbinding_boolvar ? "disabled" : ""); 
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.kbinding_namevar, new { @class = "classname", @is_disabled })
```

The html output is this :

```
<input class="classname" isDisabled="disabled" data-val="true" name="kbinding_textbox_name" type="text" value="" />
```

instead of :

```
<input class="classname" disabled data-val="true" name="kbinding_textbox_name" type="text" value="" />
```

What's the correct syntax to use to achieve the result?

Comment: you have missed the values try `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.kbinding_namevar, new { @class = "classname", disabled = is_disabled})` what happens is, asp.net mvc is taking the attribute and value i.e both as `is_disabled`. You have to explicitly say the attribute name. Alternativey you can name your variable as `disabled ` and then you don't need an explicit attribute name

Answer (score 5):

Define the attributes as an object

```
@{
    var attributes = Model.kbinding_boolvar ? 
    (object)new { @class = "classname", disabled = "disabled" } :
    (object)new { @class = "classname"};
}

@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.kbinding_namevar, attributes)
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you have missed the attribute name i.e `disabled` because your variable name is different then attribute. That's why you see this;

```
 <input class="classname" isDisabled="disabled"  data-val="true"   name="kbinding_textbox_name" type="text" value="" />
```

If you rename your variable same like an attribute i.e `isDisabled` to `disabled` like below then it will give you correctly result;

```
@{ string disabled= (Model.kbinding_boolvar ? "disabled" : ""); }
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.kbinding_namevar, new { @class = "classname", disabled})
```

Or be explicit

```
@{ string isDisabled = (Model.kbinding_boolvar ? "disabled" : ""); }
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.kbinding_namevar, new { @class = "classname", disabled = is_disabled})
```

**Note**: You don't need `@` i.e `@is_disabled` as you are already in code expression

Comment: Thank you, i have already tried this solution but does not work because when in html ther's the key "disabled" the component is always disabled with any value (ex disabled="No")

Comment: agree but your generated html code it isn't the key but the value i.e `isDisabled="disabled"` which is not a valid attribute (`isDisabled`)  if its like this `disabled="disabled"` then it will work or just like this `disabled`