# Conditional html attribute with Html Helper

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, html-helper

I am using a Html helper to create a checkbox. Pending some condition, I want to add the `disabled` attribute to the htmlAttribute object. I have the following code:

```
@if (Model.IsAuthorized)
{
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => @Model.Property, new { @class = "input-class" })
}
else
{
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => @Model.Property, new { @class = "input-class", @disabled = "disabled" })
}
```

I'd like to make this code more terse. Is there a way to conditionally add certain html attributes in one line/without a block conditional?

Comment: An alternative is [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33892728/asp-net-mvc-inserts-string-inside-new-object-parameter/33892904#33892904) but disabling a checkbox generated by `CheckBoxFor` means that it will always post back `false` even if the checkbox is checked which would cause binding to fail

Comment: Please reference this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8061647/conditional-html-attributes-using-razor-mvc3

Answer (score 10):

While you could use

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Property, Model.IsAuthorized ? (object)new { @class = "input-class", disabled = "disabled" } : (object)new { @class = "input-class"});
```

to do this in one line of code, in your case it may result in model binding failing.

The `CheckBoxFor()` method generates 2 inputs, a checkbox with `value="True"` and a hidden input with `value="False"`. In the case where the initial value of `Property` is `true` and `IsAuthorized` is `true` the result is that the checkbox is disabled and will not post a value. However the hidden input will be submitted and bind to your model, resulting in `Property` being `false` (when it should be `true`)

In order to handle model binding correctly, you will need the `if` block

```
@if (Model.IsAuthorized)
{
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => m.Property, new { @class = "input-class" })
}
else
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Property) // necessary to post back the initial value
    <input type="checkbox" @(Model.Property ? "checked" : null) disabled />
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try the below code:

```
@{
 var attr = new { @class = "input-class" };
 if (Model.IsAuthorized)
 {
    attr = new { @class = "input-class", @disabled = "disabled" };
 }
}
@Html.CheckBoxFor(x => @Model.Property, attr)
```