# disable DropDownList on edit mode in asp.net mvc razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

i want to disable DropDownList on edit mode in asp.net mvc razor

i have this code:

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.FK_TypeID, new List<SelectListItem> { new SelectListItem { Text = "Select", Value = "", Selected = true } }, new { @class = "form - control" })
```

how to achive it

Comment: What is the point of a disabled dropdownlist (and its value will never be submitted), but you can use `@Html.DropDownListFor( ..... new { @class = "form - control", disabled = "disabled" })`

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't be difficult if you know when the view is in edit mode. Please refer below:

```
@if(isEditMode == true)
{
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.FK_TypeID, new List<SelectListItem> { new SelectListItem { Text = "Select", Value = "", Selected = true } }, new { @class = "form - control",@disabled="disabled" })
}
else{
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.FK_TypeID, new List<SelectListItem> { new SelectListItem { Text = "Select", Value = "", Selected = true } }, new { @class = "form - control" })
}
```

Is this what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

i found a shorter solution using

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ID, new List<SelectListItem> { new SelectListItem { Text = "Select", Value = "", Selected = true } }, @Model.ID>0 ? (object)new { @class = "form - control", @disabled = "disabled" } : (object)new { @class = "form - control" })
```

with the help of this link
[Conditional html attribute with Html Helper](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34889685/5193454)