# Set Html.TextBoxFor not editable depending on a Model value

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm developing an ASP.NET MVC 5 app with Razor, C# and .NET Framework 4.7.

I want to make it a textbox not editable if `Model.IsChinaProduct` is true.

I have this piece of code in a View:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Configurations[index].PkgRatio, new { @class = "productClass", @onkeydown = "IsValidKey(event);" @if (Model.IsChinaProduct) disabled})
```

I want to add the `disabled` attribute if `Model.IsChinaProduct` is true, but that code shows me the following error:

> Error CS0746  Invalid anonymous type member declarator. Anonymous type
>   members must be declared with a member assignment, simple name or
>   member access.

How can I add the `disabled` attribute if `Model.IsChinaProduct` is true?

**UPDATE:**
Maybe disabled is not the right attribute.

Comment: You are inside a function, creating an anonymous type.. `if` statements are not valid in an anonymous type declaration.  You probably just want the disabled property set to true or false.

Comment: Do you really want it disabled (disabled inputs do not submit a value)? Since you have other attributes as well, then refer  [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34889537/conditional-html-attribute-with-html-helper/34889685#34889685) for an example

Comment: @StephenMuecke Sorry, no. I want to make it not editable. Sorry.

Comment: @VansFannel Then you need to use `readonly` attribute instead for non-editable textbox. You can perform the same way as duplicate link above but with `readonly = "readonly"` attribute.

Comment: The what you want is a `readonly = "readonly"` attribute

Comment: Refer this :'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6660146/set-disable-attribute-based-on-a-condition-for-html-textboxfor'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK you can't, because there is no `disabled="false"`, meaning you should do something like that:

```
@{
    var htmlAttributes = Model.IsChinaProduct ? (object)
        new { @class = "productClass", readonly = "readonly" }
        : new { @class = "productClass", @onkeydown = "IsValidKey(event);" };
}
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Configurations[index].PkgRatio, htmlAttributes)
```

Comment: That will not work - you need to cast to `object` - `var htmlAttributes Model.IsChinaProduct ? (object)new { ... } : (object)new { ... }`

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks, fixed. I always forget that until the compiler reminds me ;-)...

Answer (score 0):

For setting it *ReadOnly*, try this:

```
@{
   object displayMode = (Model.IsChinaProduct) ? new { @class = "productClass", @onkeydown = "IsValidKey(event);" } 
                                               : new { @class = "productClass", @onkeydown = "IsValidKey(event);" readonly = "readonly"};
   @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Configurations[index].PkgRatio, displayMode)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont use TextBoxFor if IsChinaProduct = true
Try DisplayFor combine with HiddenFor instead

like this

```
@if (Model.IsChinaProduct)
 {
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Configurations[index].PkgRatio)
     @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Configurations[index].PkgRatio)
 }
 else
 {
     @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Configurations[index].PkgRatio)
 }
```