# How to disable TextAreaFor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

How to disabled text are in mvc. I am using mvc 4.0. below is my code, I want to make conditionally means if m.Changes values length >0 then it should be disable,else it is enabled.
how that be possible?

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Changes , new { style = " width:97%; height:50px;", tabindex = 5 })
```

Comment: You can conditionally disable the control as per [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33892728/asp-net-mvc-inserts-string-inside-new-object-parameter/33892904#33892904), but you do realize disabled controls do not post back a value, so model binding will fail?

Answer (score 5):

Conditional disabling is only possible by using JavaScript. First, you need to set an id:

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Changes , new { style = " width:97%; height:50px;", tabindex = 5, id = "someId" })
```

And assuming you use jQuery:

```
$('#someId').on('keyUp', function() {
    var text = $('#someId').val();
    if (text.length > 0)
      $('#someId').attr('disabled','disabled');
});
```

I'd like to note, however, that disabling some textbox when the length of it's content is greater than zero, that is, it *has any content*, just makes no sense, since disabling it will prevent you from modifying it ever again (unless there is some logic that programmatically re-enables it based on some condition).

If your goal is to disable the control if the length of the value *on the server* is greater than zero (that is, the `Changes` property has a not null and non-empty value inside the model), then you could do this:

```
@if (Model.Changes.Length > 0) {
   @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Changes , new { style = " width:97%; height:50px;", tabindex = 5, id = "someId", disabled = "disabled" }) 
} else {
   @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Changes , new { style = " width:97%; height:50px;", tabindex = 5, id = "someId" }) 
}
```

If you need to disable it based on a client-side condition, then you can't avoid writing a scipt to do that.

Comment: @balazs- is there any way to do it without writing script for it.only with property like I have set as style="width:97%" like that...

Answer (score 1):

It is not trivial, because the *presence* of the `disabled` attribute will already disable the element, whether or not the attribute actually has a value.

So you can't do something like this:

```
new { disabled = Model.Changes.Length == 0 }
```

You could write an extension method that supports this, as shown in [Set disable attribute based on a condition for Html.TextBoxFor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6660146/set-disable-attribute-based-on-a-condition-for-html-textboxfor). This extension method has a `bool disabled` parameter, which when true will insert the proper `disabled="disabled"` attribute.

Comment: You can just wrap the helper inside an `if..else` block and include or omit the disabled property of the `htmlAttributes` object accordingly. If you have to do such a thing at many places, then your solution is indeed better.

Comment: Yeah you don't want to copy-paste your `Html.TextAreaFor()`, that's a maintenance hell.